# Is the given subset a subspace of the given vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The set of all polynomials of degree greater than 3 together with the zero polynomial in the vector space *P* of all polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb R$.

---

Let $S$ be the set of all polynomials of degree greater than 3 and the zero polynomial.

We have $S \neq \emptyset$ since $0 \in S$

and $S \subseteq P$

Also, for $\forall r,s \in \Bbb R$ and any $m,n>3$ , $rx^m+sx^n \in S$

Thus, $S$ is closed under addition

And for any $s \in \Bbb R$, $s*rx^n \in S$

Thus, $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication

Therefore, $S$ is a subspace of the vector space $P$ of all polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb R$.

---

However, according to the back of my book, $S$ is not a subspace of $P$. I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

$S$ is not closed under addition. Consider $ x+x^4$ and $x-x^4$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Polynomials of a certain degree can have lower order terms added to them. Can you see how leading terms may cancel when you add two polynomials in your subset, giving you a polynomial not in your subset?

Comment: Yes, I seem to have overlooked the rest of the terms in the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a polynomial of degree 4 or higher, we can write $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots a_1x+a_0$$ with $n\geq 4,a_n\neq 0$. It is not just $x^m$ with $m\geq 4$. This is where your "proof" goes wrong.

Counterexamples should now be easy to find (see also user2566092 and Alex S).

Answer (score 1):

What happens if $r=-s$ and $m=n$?

Comment: This would actually work as we get the zero polynomial as a result. ;)

Comment: Yes, that was an error on my part because of how I set up the problem. Considering the degree of the polynomial was $m$, then the result wouldn't necessarily be the zero polynomial.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in case there were more terms. The idea has been understood by OP, so I won't delete or edit my answer, for the moment.

Comment: @ajotatxe I thought you were referring to OPs $r^xm+sx^n$. With more terms than just $x^m,x^n$ this would of course be the way to go.